# Laravel image upload creating folder instead of file

Tags: image, upload, laravel

When I try to upload image from the form , Laravel is creating directory out of image name. Here is my basic code:

```
$file = Input::file("image");
$file = $file->move(public_path(). "/img/".$file->getClientOriginalName());

//file name is IPC_diagram.png
```

When die and dump I got this:

'/var/www/php/frbit/l4blog/public/img/**IPC_diagram.png/phpvEb9zk**'

Now name of image is name of new folder and image is renamed to some random php string, and placed in that folder. 
What is the problem. Maybe something related to Linux specific handling of files. Also I was looking into symfony code for this, and symfony is trying to crete new folder every time file is moved but I don't understand how it is related to my code.

Thanks for help.

Comment: My mistake - there are two arguments in the move function. First is path to directory and second (optional) is file name. So I should split the with comma.

Comment: you should add this as the answer. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use dot. Use comma, like this:

```
$name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
$file->move('uploads/posts/',$name);
```